# how to get POST webhook with geo data from Whatsapp - while using studio flow

Tags: twilio, webhooks, whatsapp

So i use studio flow for a whatsapp interaction. Sometimes our users lack internet, so we have an option to send locations in offline mode.

Once reconnected, we initiate a http_request in studio, that then uses the Twilio API to get all the inbound messages the user has been sending to whatsapp while offline. The http request only gets the last message send, so not the previous maybe 6 - 20 messages.

I can get the body text of all those, when i perform CLIENT.messages.stream. But not the geo information. As those are send in the Webhook POST request, that go to studio flow.

My question is thus how can i get the latitude/longitude? Is it possible at all?

Comment: I am trying to get more information on this. But for now, when I sent my location via WhatsApp I cannot seem to find that data via the Twilio messaging API, so for now, the only solution I see is to accept the data in a webhook and store it in a database which you can retrieve later.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio does not store the geolocation data sent via WhatsApp. So you'll have to accept the geolocation data via the webhook HTTP request and store it somewhere else if you need to retrieve it later.